# Laravel in PHP General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $id = DB::table('utilisateur')
        ->select('idUtlstr')
        ->where('email','=',$request ->input("email"))
        ->get();

    DB::table('client')->insert(
        [
            'idClient' => $id, 
            'nbrSignl' => 0,
            'numPermis' => 0, 
            'quest1' => 'vide',
            'quest2' => 'vide',
            'quest3'=> 'vide',
            'datePermis' => '2000-01-01',
            'numCompte' => 0 ,
            'blocage' => 'non' 
        ]
    );
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"idUtlstr":25}]' for column 'idClient' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `client` (`idClient`, `nbrSignl`, `numPermis`, `quest1`, `quest2`, `quest3`, `datePermis`, `numCompte`, `blocage`) values ([{"idUtlstr":25}], 0, 0, vide, vide, vide, 2000-01-01, 0, non))

Comment: Looks like the error message shows you exactly which col is not an integer...   What's your question?

Comment: when i try to put what is inside the $id in my the column 'idClient' ii get this error i didn't understand how the get the the value 25 from (idUtlstr) that it is saved in $id

Comment: It's a simple object array.  See @flash Thunder's answer below

Comment: this is my first time working on this ... thanx man

Answer (score 2):

This is because `$id` is not an integer after your database request. Your query returns an object that is element collection and you need to get it properly...

Do `var_dump($id)` and you will see that it returns `stdClass`.

Use this after query:

```
$my_id = $id{0}->idUtlstr
```

And use that variable in second query.

Comment: so the result of any executed query is an array to get data from it i treat it as an array object !! thanks man u saved me

Comment: what happen if db no record??  @aymenmedjader

Comment: myid will be null and second query will return nothing, but shouldn't fail

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$utilisateur = DB::table('utilisateur')
    ->select('idUtlstr')
    ->where('email',$request->input("email"))
    ->first();
if (!empty($utilisateur)) {
   $id = $utilisateur->idUtlstr;  
   $data = [
      'idClient' => $id, 
      'nbrSignl' => 0,
      'numPermis' => 0, 
      'quest1' => 'vide',
      'quest2' => 'vide',
      'quest3'=> 'vide',
      'datePermis' => '2000-01-01',
      'numCompte' => 0 ,
      'blocage' => 'non' 
   ];
   DB::table('client')->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: This is still incorrect. `$id` will still be an object array and raise the same error. Additionally, answers should be accompanied by an explanation, not just a code dump

Comment: but $id is an array i can't put it into the column diracty so i need to point in what i want to get ..thanx man check @flash answer it's correct

Comment: I use  ->first() method not ->get(). and this code also is correct@aymenmedjader

Comment: when you use get() it return *Collection* instance, when first it return  single data

Answer (score 0):

Use This, I hope it will works.

```
$id = DB::table('utilisateur')
            ->select('idUtlstr')
            ->where('email','=',$request ->input("email"))
            ->first();

        DB::table('client')->insert(
            [
                'idClient' => $id->idUtlstr, 
                'nbrSignl' => 0,
                'numPermis' => 0, 
                'quest1' => 'vide',
                'quest2' => 'vide',
                'quest3'=> 'vide',
                'datePermis' => '2000-01-01',
                'numCompte' => 0 ,
                'blocage' => 'non' 
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$id` is an **integer** and the query returns an **object**. For example the `$id` value equals to 2 in your database, but the query returns it as `'{"id":2}'` not `2`.

What you should do is add a second variable to get the id:

`$myid = $id->id`

This equals to `$myid = 2`. Then you can use `$myid` for your second query and everything will work fine.

Based on your code, this should work:

```
$id = DB::table('utilisateur')
    ->select('idUtlstr')
    ->where('email','=',$request ->input("email"))
    ->get();
    $myid = $id->id

DB::table('client')->insert(
    [
        'idClient' => $myid, 
        'nbrSignl' => 0,
        'numPermis' => 0, 
        'quest1' => 'vide',
        'quest2' => 'vide',
        'quest3'=> 'vide',
        'datePermis' => '2000-01-01',
        'numCompte' => 0 ,
        'blocage' => 'non' 
    ]
);
```