# Incorrect integer value: '[]' for column at row 1 in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys i am trying to store id value  from one table to another table column (topic_lookup_masters_id).

so far i have made a join query and trying to get that id..so while storing i am getting error as

```
General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[]' for column 'topic_lookup_master_id' at row 1
```

Here is my store function:

```php
$Topic_id = DB::table('topic_lookup_masters')
    ->join('qtype_lookup_masters', 'qlm_topic_id', '=', 'topic_lookup_masters.tlm_topic_id')
    ->select('topic_lookup_masters.id')
    ->get();

$qtype_lookup_master = new Qtype_lookup_master();
$qtype_lookup_master->topic_lookup_master_id = $Topic_id;
```

Tried using the type cast as (int) but still its not working.

Comment: Probably it returns a null value, Did you try `$Topic_id->id;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel in PHP General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647151/laravel-in-php-general-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value)

Answer (score -1):

Probably you try to populate the 'topic_lookup_masters_id' with a string or with null. Check if the associated value is int.

Comment: Yes in console it was showing null..but where i did mistake from query?